# Android How to hide server url for security in code?

Tags: android

My application need to communicate frequently.
So there are many url: http://abc.php
The question is even if I use proguard, is it possible for people to get the url and hack in the system.
What should I do so that it can hide the link and make my system more secure.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Any one can get you app and use sniffers to check where your application sends request. You should provide good security on server.

Answer (score 2):

Any URL or web service you are sending them to should only be for uses such as JSON/XML requests. There shouldn't be anything that critical in a wide open base URL. If there is then you have problems to begin with. Plus you may try to hide your URL, but with simple networking tools attached to the application it would be very easy to sniff the IP address and do other public functions to look-up the url. Any URL you have would be public, thus you need to take security measures on another end.

Comment: Hey can I just merge my answer with Nikita Beloglazov above me. He beat me to the punch, but he is absolutely correct.